# Is there a way to use sudo for a salt master just like a minion?

Tags: salt-stack

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Salt Ver: 2015.8.7+ds-1

I don't want to use root as the user for starting the salt stack master. I've followed the instructions for running as another user instead of root:

- specified the user under the master config
- changed the permissions to match the user for /etc/salt /var/cache/salt /var/log/salt /var/run/salt

It doesn't work. After a restart, all the permissions under /var/cache/salt is reverted to root and it has issues with running dmidecode. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a simple user for running the salt master. I had some troubles with permissions but it is doable. I have dmidecode warnings too but it should not have any impact because it's more a minion job.

What I did:

1. Stop salt master
2. Edit `/etc/salt/master` to add `user: salt` parameter, or use a file in `/etc/salt/master.d/`
3. Set new owner:

   `chown -Rh salt:salt /etc/salt/master \
                        /etc/salt/master.d \
                        /var/cache/salt/master \
                        /srv/salt`
4. Remove access to '/etc/salt/minion.d' directory: [issue #29831](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/29831)

   `chmod o-rwx /etc/salt/minion.d`
5. Start salt master

I think that's all.